# PHP charset having issues

Tags: php, mysql

I don't usually have issues on charset, but this one I'm not getting where the problem is.

```
function categories($host, $user, $pw, $bd){
    $file_handle = fopen("categories.csv", "rb");

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $bd);
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
        $parts = explode(';', $line_of_text);

        $description = $parts[1];
        $parent = $parts[2];

        $query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO categories (`description`, parent) VALUES(?, ?)");
        $query->bind_param("si", $description, $parent);
        $query->execute();
    }
    fclose($file_handle);   
}
```

I do have the same code for others files, like countries, etc and I have no problem with charset.
As you can see I use, as always, the `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` code. If I echo the `$description` variable I do get the right characters (they are mostly portuguese).

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); // inside the function
$query->execute();

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // in the top of the page
```

But it continues to add in the database words like: Feij?o (Feijão), Ch?s (Chás).

I do find this stupid because I do insert in another table, like I said, countries names with accents without any problem.

Any guess?

**Edit:** Solved, using utf8_encode.

```
$query->bind_param("si", utf8_encode($description), $parent);
```

Comment: Make sure PHP is setup to deal with utf-8: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`. You could also try: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Portuguese_Portugal.1252');`

Comment: Check if the fields, tables and database charset are also `utf-8`, not only your connection.

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably is in file "categories.csv", which could not be UTF-8...

To convert the file from "ASCII" to UTF-8 you could use

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8 categories.csv
```

Comment: I opened categories.csv with notepad++ and its codification is "ANSII", if I change that to UTF-8, it will put the special characters with `믣` this.

Comment: Try converting each field of your CSV with `iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $str);`

Comment: @MarceloPascual I receive (for the fields which have special characters): Detected an illegal character in input string

Comment: You should probably convert the file before reading it from php (see my updated answer...).